# Server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type) - vue.js and python django

Tags: django, vue.js

I am sending a registration request, and get this error:

> {"errors":[{"detail":"Unsupported media type
>   \"application/json;charset=UTF-8\" in
>   request.","source":{"pointer":"/data"},"status":"415"}]}

This is how I send data in vue.js:

```
import {instanceAxios} from '@/services/interceptor';
const registration = async ({commit}, data) => {
    try {
        let resp = await instanceAxios.post('/account/register/', data);
        const token = resp.data.token;
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        instanceAxios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Token ${token}`;
        commit('AUTH_SUCCESS', resp.data);
        return resp;
    } catch (e) {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        throw e;
    }
};
```

And I get this error.

this is how my request looks in browser:

[image]
Very ineteresting thing that content type is application
Also I can give you code from backend register method
https://pastebin.com/74zXjejV

PS: i don't know why but I get content type application/d.json - that is strange

Answer (score 2):

A 415 error means that your payload is invalid [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415).

If you're sending json try this

```
instanceAxios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/account/register/',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    });
```

instead of

```
instanceAxios.post('/account/register/', data);
```

and check if your body is valid